# P, Q, R, S four points lie in a plane and PQ = PR = QR = PS then how many possible values of angle QSR can exist?

Tags: geometry

P, Q, R, S four points lie in a plane and PQ = PR = QR = PS then how many possible values of angle QSR can exist?

I think 2 values because PQRS is either a square or rhombus.

Comment: As written, triangle PQR is equilateral...

Comment: There are 2 values, but PQRS is neither a square nor a rhombus, since, for example, PQR is an equilateral triangle. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r = PQ = PR = QR = PS$. The triangle $PQR$ is equilateral with side length $r$ and $S$ is some point on the circle with center $P$ and radius $r$ (this circle also passes through $Q$ and $R$). The angle $QSR$ is [therefore half](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InscribedAngle.html) of $QPR$, i.e., $30$ degrees, when $S$ is on the big arc $QR$ of the circle, and is $180$ minus that, i.e., $150$ degrees, when $S$ is on the small arc $QR$ of the circle.

Comment: You might want to mention the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) and use [this diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FIacT.png).

Comment: Thanks for the diagram, @robjohn. I didn't refer to the inscribed angle theorem by name, but I did include a link to MathWorld's page on it.